# Overriding another product's view template in Plone

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 4.1.2 and I am trying to override a view template provided by collective.contenleadimage.  It is easy to edit the provided template via portal_view_customization but I want to try doing it from my policy product in the filesystem.

I would like to replace the folder_leadimage_view of c.contentleadimage.

This is what I have done in my policy product.

**in interfaces.py**

```
from zope.interface import Interface

class IExamplePolicy(Interface):
    """Marker interface that defines a Zope 3 browser layer.
    """
```

**in profiles/default/browserlayer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layers>
    <layer name="example.policy" 
           interface="example.policy.interfaces.IExamplePolicy" />
</layers>
```

**in browser/configure.zcml**

```
<configure
xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml"
i18n_domain="example.policy">


<browser:page
     for="Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IBaseFolder"
     name="folder_leadimage_view"
     class="collective.contentleadimage.browser.folder_leadimage_view.FolderLeadImageView"
     template="folder_leadimage_view.pt"
     layer="..interfaces.IExamplePolicy"
     permission="zope2.View"
     allowed_attributes="tag"
/>

<browser:page
     for="Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IPloneSiteRoot"
     name="folder_leadimage_view"
     class="collective.contentleadimage.browser.folder_leadimage_view.FolderLeadImageView"
     template="folder_leadimage_view.pt"
     layer="..interfaces.IExamplePolicy"
     permission="zope2.View"
 />
```

My policy product installs fine and I can see in portal_view_customization

```
Products.Archetypes.interfaces.base.IBaseFolder
    folder_leadimage_view (example.policy.interfaces.IExamplePolicy)
    folder_leadimage_view (collective.contentleadimage.interfaces.ILeadImageSpecific)
```

However, my new template is not the one rendered by Plone.

I would appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `interfaces.py` to:

```
from collective.contentleadimage.interfaces import ILeadImageSpecific

class IExamplePolicy(ILeadImageSpecific):
    """Marker interface that overrides collective.contentleadimage's
    browser layer.
    """
```

Browser layers are markers applied to the request. Both your `IExamplePolicy` and collective.contentleadimage's `ILeadImageSpecific` browser layers are applied, but by inheriting from `ILeadImageSpecific` for your browser layer you make your overridden `folder_leadimage_view` view *more specific* than collective.contentleadimage's own.

For more information on  Zope Component Architecture *interface resolution order* see the "Customisation with more-specific adapters" section in [the Dexterity manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/five.grok/core-components/adapters).

Comment: Thanks.  This worked well.  I will checkout the Dexterity manual.